# How to implement a output window in PyQt5 application?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 and looking for a related function as I saw in Agros2D, which is also developed by Qt.

Its user interface looks like this
[image]

I draw a red circle to point this out.
What is that called in PyQt5? It seems not to be 'MessageBox'. And how to use it? I would like to output some information about imported data in the embedded window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a QDockWidget with a QTextEdit:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
w.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
w.resize(640, 480)
w.show()

log_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(readOnly=True)
log_edit.append("""<div style="color:green">This is a paragraph.</div>""")
log_edit.append("""<div style="color:blue">This is a paragraph.</div>""")

log_dock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget("Application log")
log_dock.setWidget(log_edit)

w.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, log_dock)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. And how to print my file name. For example, my file is called `good_file`, then I add something like `log_edit.append("""<div style="color:blue">Data:{}</div>""".format(good_file))`. Is this correct?